# flutter stuck at Waiting for observatory port to be available

Tags: android-studio, flutter

[   +7 ms] Waiting for observatory port to be available...
[+2785236 ms] Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly
[+820825 ms] Error launching application on A37f.
[+1755 ms] "flutter run" took 40,20,767ms.

Comment: see once :- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33214#issuecomment-568733832

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling gradle packages helped me clear the conflicting cache,
To do so, first navigate to the terminal of android folder and execute:

```
gradlew uninstallAll
```